# Function to encode my php script using base64 encode method

Tags: php, encoding, base64

This is my code:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Buy extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('cart');
        $this->load->model(array('product_model', 'availability_master_model', 'customer_model'));
//        $this->load->model('common_model', 'obj_common', TRUE);
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->helper(array('text', 'form'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|xss_clean|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Mobile', 'required|xss_clean|numeric|min_length[10]|max_length[10]|matches[confirm]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm', 'Confirm Mobile', 'required|xss_clean|numeric|min_length[10]|max_length[10]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('land', 'Land Phone', 'xss_clean|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pincode', 'Pincode', 'required|xss_clean|numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_devices', 'Device Count', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required|xss_clean');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data['product'] = $this->availability_master_model->get_availability('2');
            $this->load->view('web/shop-online', $data);
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                'landline' => $this->input->post('land'),
                'postal_code' => $this->input->post('pincode'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
            );
            $this->db->insert('user_registration', $data);
            $user_id = $this->db->insert_id();

            redirect('buy/view_details/' . $user_id.'/'.$this->input->post('no_devices'));
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to have a fully functional encryption code for the same.All the online encoder i have used is adding some extra fields of their own to the encryption code. It is just making some security issues. So please help me to solve.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "encryption code for the same"? You want to base64 encode the script itself and still be able to run it? You should know that base64 is not an encryption method and does not prevent anyone with even the slightest clue from viewing your code.

Comment: i dont know what you want exactly but you can use base64_encode ($data ) to encode your data to base64 , and  base64_decode($str)  to decode